# C# - How to use a voided method in an if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods, void

I am writing a program that sends the user an email holding information. What I am trying to accomplish is if the email was sent successfully, then it will write to a log file that the email was sent successfully. My only problem, is that I am finding the difficulty in getting the if statement to do that. I understand that I can't put the method into the if statement because you cannot convert a voided method into boolean, but what other way could I do it? Below is the code I have tried along with my SendEmail method.

```
SendEmail(BuildEmailBody(transaction, myHomeInformation),subjectLine);
    if (SendEmail.Success())
     {
       BOAssistant.WriteLine                 
     }
```

This is the method:

```
private static void SendEmail(string emailBody, string emailSubject)
     {
        //This is the method that will create the email for you
        Email email = new Email();
        email.To.Add("POvermyer@TandT.com");
        email.Subject = emailSubject;
        email.Body = emailBody;
        email.Send();
    }
```

Comment: Return a `bool` from your `SendEmail` function saying whether it succeeded or not (I don't know how to do it with the `Email` class, but you can figure that out). Then your `if` statement would just be `if (SendEmail(body, subject)) { /* code */ }`.

Comment: You should accomplish that inside your **send email** method...either returning a value or performing the success function in there

Comment: And how do you intend to know if the email was actually sent successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (SendEmail(BuildEmailBody(transaction, myHomeInformation),subjectLine))
{
    BOAssistant.WriteLine                 
}
```

...

```
private static bool SendEmail(string emailBody, string emailSubject)
 {
    //This is the method that will create the email for you
    Email email = new Email();
    email.To.Add("POvermyer@TandT.com");
    email.Subject = emailSubject;
    email.Body = emailBody;
    try{
    email.Send();
    } catch(Exception e) { return false; }
    return true;
}
```

or

```
bool isSent;
SendEmail(BuildEmailBody(transaction, myHomeInformation),subjectLine, out isSent);
if (isSent)
{
    BOAssistant.WriteLine                 
}
```

...

```
private static void SendEmail(string emailBody, string emailSubject, out bool isSent)
 {
    //This is the method that will create the email for you
    Email email = new Email();
    email.To.Add("POvermyer@TandT.com");
    email.Subject = emailSubject;
    email.Body = emailBody;
    try{
    email.Send();
    } catch(Exception e) { isSent = false; }
    isSent = true;
}
```

or

```
SendEmail(BuildEmailBody(transaction, myHomeInformation),subjectLine, () => BOAssistant.WriteLine);
```

...

```
private static void SendEmail(string emailBody, string emailSubject, Action onSuccess)
 {
    //This is the method that will create the email for you
    Email email = new Email();
    email.To.Add("POvermyer@TandT.com");
    email.Subject = emailSubject;
    email.Body = emailBody;
    try{
    email.Send();
    } catch(Exception e) { return; }
    onSuccess();
}
```

Comment: When the method only ever returns `true` its rather pointless to have it return anything at all.

Comment: I assume the version with the `out` parameter should actually have a return type of `void` and not `bool`, especially since you don't `return` anything.  Also while that would work it is just bad design IMHO.

Comment: The first answer you provided worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Personally id go for the last one

Answer (score 2):

If you know that an unsuccessful email will throw an exception, you can handle it like this:

```
try
{
    SendEmail(BuildEmailBody(transaction, myHomeInformation),subjectLine);
    BOAssistant.WriteLine  //log success here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //unsuccessful here
}
```

Comment: Of course, that assumption *won't* actually hold true in practice.  Just because `Send` doesn't throw doesn't mean the email will actually be successfully sent/received.

Comment: Catching `Exception` type is not a very good idea most of the time. Something else might go wrong before trying to send the e-mail and it still will be caught. And how do we know that an exception will be thrown when an e-mail is not sent?

Comment: @Kapol Catching `Exception` here is almost certainly appropriate.  The response to the email not being successfully sent is almost certainly going to be exactly the same regardless of what actually caused the problem, namely to log the error and inform the user (if this isn't an automated process) that the email couldn't be sent.

Comment: @Servy Thank you for the explanation. That actually makes sense. The only problem I can think of now is an exception being thrown *after* the e-mail was sent. Of course that would happen only if we later on add some new code :-)

Comment: @Kapol Then you'd have to ask yourself if you'd actually want to do anything any different if the exception was thrown there instead.  If you would, then you'd want an additional try/catch around that method (or possibly inside that method).  In the rather likely situation that the only response to an exception in either location is to log the exception and move on, then it'd be fine just as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If your method has to be of `void` return type (that's what I assume based on the question title), then you can introduce an `out` parameter. It doesn't have to be initialized before the method call, but you have to assign a value to it inside the method itself. An `out` parameter is being passed by reference, so whatever value is assigned to it by the callee is reflected in the caller.

```
bool sentSuccessfully;
SendEmail(string emailBody, string emailSubject, out sentSuccessfully)

if(sentSuccessfully)
{
    // do whatever you need
}
```

Of course you will need to modify your `SendEmail` method to include this additional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be to change the return type of sendmail method to a bool and use it in if statement.

```
private static bool SendEmail(string emailBody, string emailSubject)
 {
   try
   {
    Email email = new Email();
    email.To.Add("POvermyer@TandT.com");
    email.Subject = emailSubject;
    email.Body = emailBody;
    email.Send();
    return true;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
    return false; 
   }
}
```

If changing the method return type is not an option then you can do this,

```
bool IsSuccessfullySent;
try
{
 SendEmail(BuildEmailBody(transaction, myHomeInformation),subjectLine);
 IsSuccessfullySent= true;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 IsSuccessfullySent=false;
}
if (IsSuccessfullySent)
 {
   BOAssistant.WriteLine                 
 }
```